# Choose from a PHP array with predefined probability

Tags: php, arrays, random, probability

To select a random value from a PHP array we can use `array_rand` method to pick randomly a index.

But if I want to select an index with specified probability, what would be the best way to do that in PHP.

To make it clear, the PHP array looks like this:

```
$array = array(
    [0] => array(
               'val' => $val,
               'probability' => $probability
           ),
    [1] => array(
           ...
    ),
    ...    
)
```

I want choose from the `$array` with specified probability.

Comment: Do you want to use stats to determine a specific probability or do you just want to define it by hand?

Comment: Here you can find some code that can help you : http://forums.phpfreaks.com/topic/187182-weighted-probability/

Comment: You can change the probability by having duplicate values in an array. If you have 'Blue' twice and 'Green' once, 'Blue' would be twice as likely to be randomly selected.

Comment: I am hard coding the probability factor to the array elements...